# how to align a image to the center of a page in ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I want to align a image (logo)to the center (both horizontal and vertical)of the page ?

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
<ion-content class="backgound-red ">
<section class = "home-container">
      <div class="row icon-row">

        <div class="col">
                    <h1 class="text-white text-center">My Application </h1>
          <h4 class ="text-white text-center ">version 1.0.0</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-center" >
        <div class="col text-center" >
            <img alt="Logo" height="100" src="img/logo.png" >
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="row icon-row">

        <div class="col ">
            <a class="text-white text-center" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://members.000webhost.com/login.php?'); return false;">
              <h5 class ="text-white text-center ">access server</h5></a>
        </div>        
    </div>
    </section>
</ion-content>
```

the layout that I want, The Image should be align center automatically to the mobile screen.(tab, phone)

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try adding this CSS code, it will center the img both horizontally and vertically.

```
.home-container .row-center img {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```